# How to use cmath Bessel functions with Mac

Tags: c++, macos, cmath

So I am using Mac with the developer tools coming from XCode and according to other answers I should compile using something like:

```
g++ --std=c++17  test.cpp -o test
```

or using `clang++` but I still I am having trouble making the script find the special functions. What else can I try?

Minimum example

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  double x = 0.5;
  double y = std::cyl_bessel_k(2,x);
  std::cout << "x="<<x <<" -> y(x)="<<y <<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Error

```
main2.cpp:6:19: error: no member named 'cyl_bessel_k' in namespace 'std'
  double y = std::cyl_bessel_k(2,x);
             ~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

clang++ version 13.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions/cyl_bessel_j says:

> ## Notes
>
> Implementations that do not support C++17, but support ISO 29124:2010,
> provide this function if `__STDCPP_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__` is defined by
> the implementation to a value at least `201003L` and if the user
> defines `__STDCPP_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__` before including any
> standard library headers.
>
> Implementations that do not support ISO 29124:2010 but support TR
> 19768:2007 (TR1), provide this function in the header `tr1/cmath` and
> namespace `std::tr1`.

Armed with your compiler version, I checked https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17#C.2B.2B17_library_features and saw that neither Apple clang nor clang++'s own stdlib have these functions. Bad news! You'll need to get them e.g. from boost, or by implementing them yourself. The example on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions/cyl_bessel_j actually does have an implementation for you.

Comment: Clang does support C++17 (they claim they're 100% compliant), yet the Bessel functions are not defined.